# Unable to Save Configurable Product Options using API

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, configurable-product-options

I am using Magento's API to add the **Configurable Product Options** but I don't see them in Configurable product data.

EndPoint Used to add the Configurable Product Options

> https://example.com/rest/default/V1/configurable-products/configurable-product-sku/options/

Payload : `{"option":{"attribute_id":"369","label":"Color","values":[{"value_index":54684}]}}`

The endpoint I used to get the configurable product

> https://example.com//rest/all/V1/products/configurable-product-sku/

Response having the Configurable product option:

```
"configurable_product_options": [
            {
                "id": 102439,
                "attribute_id": "369",
                "label": "Color",
                "position": 0,
                "values": [],
                "product_id": 2576743
            },
```

*It doesn't have the value saved using the "https://example.com/rest/default/V1/configurable-products/configurable-product-sku/options/" API.*

Below is the AP used to get the attribute values, using the attribute set.

API :

> https://example.com//rest/default/V1/products/attribute-sets/4/attributes

below is the data for the attribute used :

```
{
        "attribute_id": 369,
        "attribute_code": "color",
        "frontend_input": "select",
        "entity_type_id": "4",
        "is_required": false,
        "options": [
            {
                "label": " ",
                "value": ""
            },
            {
                "label": "Blanco",
                "value": "54683"
            },
            {
                "label": "Negro",
                "value": "54684"
            },
            {
                "label": "Gris",
                "value": "54685"
            }
        ],
        "is_user_defined": true,
        "default_frontend_label": "Color",
        "frontend_labels": [],
        "backend_type": "int",
        "source_model": "Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Table",
        "default_value": "",
        "is_unique": "0",
        "validation_rules": []
    },
```

I have followed the below reference to create the configurable product.

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/config-product-intro.html

Anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Having the exact same issue. PUT endpoint on the option also doesn't update anything. Seems to be a lack of feedback from the API / a legitimate bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add the same attribute twice to a product.

```
{"option":{"attribute_id":"194","label":"color2","position":0,"is_use_default":true,"values":[{"value_index":91},{"value_index":92},{"value_index":93}]}}
```

i only get an error when executing this request twice. I think you need to look ad updating an existing option.
Also, it looks like that the values are only saved if there are child products with that value connected to the parent.

Comment: You can't save a child product until those values exist, so not sure on how you found that?